# Vous en savez un peu plus sur moi - meaning of "en"

Tags: en

I know that the pronoun "en" replaces complements introduced by "de". Example:

- Je bois de l'eau - J'en bois.
- Je rêve de cette fête. - J'en rêve.
- Sais-tu quelque chose de mon frère? - En sais-tu quelque chose?

However, I'm a little confused with a specific usage of "en" that I just heard:

Voilà, vous en savez un peu plus sur moi.

What is "en" replacing in this sentence? "sur moi" is the complement of the verb "savoir" here and therefore I see no complement introduced by "de".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***En*** replaces the implicit things that have been learnt by the person.

> *Voilà, vous savez un peu plus **de choses** sur moi.*

You can't use that sentence without either the pronoun ***en*** or what it replaces.

> *Voilà, <s>vous savez un peu plus sur moi</s>*

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to go by the analysis given in the dictionary ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)); the relevant text issued from the dictionary is the only text highlighted in what follows.

> 3. Dans certains cas, en nombre limité, l'antécédent est sous-entendu (implicite) et se dégage de la situation en vertu de l'usage.

In the sentence under scrutiny, which is one of only a small lot of cases ("en nombre limité"), we infer from the context that the antecedent is not stated (sous-entendu, implicite); the context is however difficult to identify: we see subsequently that it is inferred from the use of certain colloquial locutions  of two types, fixed or colloquial;

- *fixed and comprising or not an adverb of quantity*: n'en pouvoir **plus**, ne pas en revenir, en avoir **assez**,  en découdre (*colloquial*), …
- *colloquial*: en dire, en entendre, en voir, en faire, …

« En » can be imprecise in a large number of ready made expressions and that should be kept in mind; this is reminded to us by LBU in § 679, the relevant paragraph being found below in italics; however, this does not apply to "en" as used int the questionned sentence.

***Valeur imprécise de en et de y.***

*a) « En » et « y » ont une valeur imprécise dans un grand nombre d'expressions :

S'en aller, s'en venir, s'en retourner (pour ces trois verbes,
voir § 681, b), en vouloir à qqn, s'en prendre à qqn (cf. 5°), ce qu'il en coûte, c'en est fait, en imposer (cf. 3°), en référer à qqn, s'en référer à qqn ou qq. ch. (cf. Ac. 1935), ne pas en mener large, s'en tenir à qq. ch., en rester là, en être, il en est (ainsi, de même, autrement, etc.), en finir, en avoir assez, c'en est trop, il en a menti, en prendre à son aise, en user avec qqn, en croire qqn, s'en tirer, s'en faire, en faire de même, en faire à sa tête, n'en rien faire, n'en pas finir, s'en tenir à, en user mal avec qqn, il s'en faut de beaucoup, etc. ; — il y a, il y va de l'honneur, il n'y paraît pas, n'y voir goutte, vous n'y êtes pas, y regarder à deux fois, il s'y prend mal, etc.*

It would be the case if there was no complement ("sur moi");

- Vous en savez des choses sur moi !
- Vous en savez des choses ! (*imprecise antecedent*) (user **LPH**'s example)

> 4. À l'intérieur de la proposition où il est placé, « en » remplit auprès des termes de cette proposition toutes les fonctions assumées par « de », soit dans ses emplois de préposition, soit dans ses emplois d'article indéfini ou partitif

In the case of the sentence questioned, "en" does not take up exactly the meaning of "de" but more specifically that of "sur";  we see that below.

> II. [Dans des loc. figées ou fam., « en » a un antécédent implicite]

In the sentence questionned which comprises a colloquial locution ("en savoir un peu plus"), "en" has an understated antecedent (implicite); this antecedent is "the whole knowledge of who is a person" (moi); notice it is not "de moi" but "sur moi".

> B. [L'antécédent représente une proposition antécédente, ou une idée parfois vague tirée du contenu]

The antecedent is an idea extracted from the content (sometimes this idea is vague), not a clause (proposition).

> 2. « en » = sur cela (qui a été dit ou qui va l'être)

In this questionned sentence "qui va l'être" is not right and "cela" is "tout ce qu'il y a à savoir me concernant"; the idea is extracted from "moi", which is not the antecedent but is taken up into it and thereby causes a redundance; however, it is necessary to add the complement "sur moi" if an antecedent is to be inferred. One must admit that  all of that is quite messy.

> c) [En relation avec un adv. de quantité] En savoir long, en apprendre davantage.
>
> - Combien de journaux de captivité pourraient en dire autant?
> - Elle fit un mouvement pour se lever, comme si elle avait craint d'en entendre davantage.
> - les légendes locales en savaient long sur les conciliabules qu'avaient abrités ces coupoles mauresques et ces hautes voûtes noires aux suintements de cave...

This use of the pronoun is a use with an accepted  redundance; this is made salient in LBU § 680, "*en* et *y* redondants". Here are examples issued from this source, which show that in certain cases the redundance can be avoided by getting rid of "en" ;

- *Ne pas en revenir de : « avoir peine à croire, à accepter »*
- *Mon ami n'EN revenait pas de l'audace de cette « clique ».  (PROUST, Rech., t. II, p. 183)*
- *Mes camarades communistes « n'EN revenaient pas » d'être là.  (Cl. ROY, cit.
  Rob. 2001, s. v. revenir, C, 2)*
- *Je n'EN reviens pas qu'il ait réussi à son examen.  (Dict. contemp.)*

***Sans en*** (seul tour signalé par l'Ac. 1935)

- *La douairière ne revenait pas de ce que les cloches portassent jusqu'ici.  (PROUST, Rech., t. II, p. 822)*

**Ex. où « en » ne fait pas double emploi**

- *Elle n'EN [= de ce qu'elle avait appris 8 jours avant, voir chap. précédent] revenait pas...Des dettes !... Un enfant !... (E. et J. DE GONC., Germ. Lacerteux, LXIX.)*

---

If the sentence questioned is written in terms of replaced elements, the redundance becomes salient.

- Voilà, sur tout ce qu'il y a à savoir me (**moi**) concernant vous savez un peu plus sur moi.

It is removed as follows (among other possibilities);

- Voilà, vous savez (maintenant)  un peu plus sur tout ce qu'il y a à savoir me concernant.

Comment: Réponse incroyablement détaillée.

Answer (score 1):

What I see as implicit in the sentence and what I think *en* refers to is :

- Voilà, vous en savez un peu plus [de ce qu'on peut savoir] sur moi / You know a bit more [of what there is to know] about me.

But you'd have to say :

- Voilà, vous savez tout sur moi.
- Voilà, vous ne savez rien sur moi.

Maybe because *tout* and *rien* represent absolute degrees of knowledge at both ends of the spectrum (*everything* and *nothing*).  Whereas if knowledge is only partial (*more, a bit more, a lot more, not even half etc. of what you can know*) *en* surfaces in the sentence :

- Voilà, vous en savez plus sur moi.
- Voilà, vous en savez un peu plus sur moi.
- Voilà, vous en savez bien plus sur moi.
- Voilà, vous n'en savez même pas la moitié sur moi.

It should be noted that if you use *presque* with *rien* or *tout* (almost nothing, almost everything), *en* doesn't appear, as if the phrase *presque tout/rien sur moi* still tilted toward absolute and not partial knowledge :

- Voilà, vous savez presque tout sur moi.
- Voilà, vous ne savez presque rien sur moi.