# Vous en pensez -- why do we need "en" there?

Tags: grammaire, en

> Nous voulons vraiment savoir ce que vous **en** pensez.

I don't understand how **en** is used in this sentence. The sentence makes perfect sense without it: **we really want to know what you think**. But why do we actually need it there? What's its grammatical and semantic function in this case?

Comment: This use of *en* is exactly the same as the one in [this answer by @jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37488/358). Just replace *en savoir* by *en penser*.

Comment: How would you rephrase that sentence without the *en* as Jlliagre did in his answer?

Comment: "Nous voulons vraiment savoir ce que vous pensez *de ça*."

Comment: Your traduction is not quite right. To keep the "en", you'd have to translate to : *We really want to know what you think **of it***.

Comment: @RomainValeri translation, we say in English. penser de ceci, penser de cela. But I urge you to learn how to use the en, as it is very frequent in French with verbs followed by de.

Comment: @Lambie Ouch, that's embarassing, yeah sorry I typed too quickly but of course it's *translation*. But I guess you've mistaken me for a french learner here ;-) I know how to use "en".

Comment: @RomainValeri No, my second comment was not directed at you. It was directed at the OP, of course. I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*En* is a personal pronoun here, it may refer to a thing or things. (Genitive case, partitive use, governed by the preposition de) :

> Qu'est-ce que vous pensez de cette idée ?→
>   Qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ?
>
> Nous voulons vraiment savoir ce que vous en pensez.→
>   We really want to know what you are thinking (about it).

Some other pertinent examples are in order now:

> A-t-il compris l'importance de son entretien ?
>   Bien sûr, Il en a compris l'importance.
>
> La professeure a continué la lecture de l'histoire.→
>   La professeure en a continué la lecture.
>
> Voulez-vous du café ? J'ai très envie d'en prendre.
>
> Nous n'avons plus de billets aujourd'hui. Est-ce il y en aura demain ?
>
> Avez-vous du fromage. Je regrette mais j'en ai pas.
>
> Tu as trouvé beaucoup de fautes ? J'en ai trouvé huit.
>
> Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres clientes ? Il n'y en a pas d'autres.
>
> Il en a pris une poignée→He took a handful (of it).
>
> Je n'en aurais plus besoin d'aujourd'hui.
>
> Elle s'en souvient→She remembered it.

*En* as personal pronoun can mean also "from there".

> Il en a bougé pas. → He didn't move from there.
>
> Il y a va à huit heures, et il en revient vers midi.→
>   He goes there at eight o'clock and comes back (from there) around midday.

Comment: There is no genitive case in English. English is not declined, unlike Greek or Latin.

Comment: A few corrections: Elle s'en souvient -> She remembers it ; Il (n') en a pas bougé ; Il y va à huit heures